# Ajax Html Editor Extender - Cannot get height

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, editor

okay so I was messing around with the relatively new Ajax Html Editor Extender (NOT Ajax Html Editor) and I've got a problem with it.

Basicly what I want to get is the height of the Editor via javascript but it will not tell me what the height is no matter what i do. The reason why i need the height of the editor is because it is inside a div (a wrapper div) with relative position. and i need that div to "follow" the editor but the editor just "jumps" out of the div, like shown in image below:

[image: Example]

I have tried in many ways to get the height of the editor:
- with the id of the textbox that ive put the extender on (returns 16)
- and many other ids that i saw in DOM code of my page.
- but none of them will tell me the real height.

then i looked at the source code for ajax toolkit
and there are class names like:

`.ajax__html_editor_extender_buttoncontainer`

`.ajax__html_editor_extender_container`

and so on...

but trying go get those heights with jQuery only returns null.

So my question guys is
how do i get the height of the actual editor,
or how do i make it relative, so it will (in one way or the other)
be followed by the wrapper div?

Comment: okay i found the height using id=globalcontent_admincontent_HtmlEditorExtender1_ExtenderContentEditable... So with that i can control the wrapper height... thx anyways

Answer (score 0):

Okay apparently I could use this id to get the height of the edittable:

HtmlEditorExtender1_ExtenderContentEditable

All though not the best way as I see it, because then u have to set wrapper height all the time with javascript - but a solution none the less...